# How to bind an AspxListBox to more than two properties

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

Maybe the title isn't clear enough.

I have a data set whose objects have a key, a text and description. how do i bind this description property to the list box so that i can manipulate in client-side?
I cannot show the description to the user and its not something i can derive from the key and text.

--EDIT--
apparently i cannot submit the question as-is, i need to show what i have done so far:

```
//lbTemplates_OnCallback
            var elementIds = new[] { SmsElementKey };// ConfiguredElements.Split(',').Select(long.Parse).ToArray();
            var v = smsTemplateDao.ListByElementTypes(elementIds);
            lbTemplates.DataSource = v;
            lbTemplates.DataBind();
            lbTemplates.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

The markup:

```
<dx:ASPxListBox ID="lbTemplates" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="lbTemplates" EnableViewState="False" Height="210px" OnCallback="lbTemplates_OnCallback" Width="220px"  ValueField="ParkElementId" TextField="ElementPath">
<ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="UpdateButtons" Init="UpdateButtons" />
</dx:ASPxListBox>
```

Comment: Are you unable to show the description to the user currently and is it that you want to show the description to the user on your web form using a list box that contains a list of descriptions with something that is selected? replying would help rephrase your question to something more meaningful

Answer (score 0):

You may use both DataTextField and DataValueField.